# ¿Por qué no alinea los elementos?

Tags: html, css

Quiero que los elementos en "***contenedorInput***" centre tanto el **label** como los **inputs**, ya les puse un ***width*** para que tenga su espacio, hay dos lineas dentro de ese contenedor, no entiendo porque no los quiere centrar.

Tampoco me quiere tomar el **display:block**, se supone que si yo pongo eso en el elemento **div** contenedor del label y inputs deberia ponerlos en bloque uno abajo del otro. Porqué no lo hace?

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.contenedor{
    border-radius: 15px;
    height: 280px;
    width: 70%;
    top: 100px;
    padding: 25px;
    background-color: crimson;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
}

.formularioClase{
    margin: 25px;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.contenedorInput{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Calculadora</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Estilos/estilos.css"/>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="contenedor">
        <h1>Calculadora con JS</h1>

        <form class="formularioClase" id="formCalculadoraID">
            <div class="contenedorInput">
                <label for="operandoA">Operando A</label>
                <input type="number" placeholder="Ingresa el primer operando" class="inputClass" id="operandoA"/>
            </div>
            <div class="contenedorInput">
                <label for="operandoB">Operando B</label>
                <input type="number" placeholder="Ingresa el segundo operando" class="inputClass" id="operandoB"/>
            </div>
        </form>

        <button class="botonResultado">Resultado</button>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Casi lo tienes, sucede que nunca estás haciendo flexible al div `contenedorInput` para que obedezcan las clases `justify-content` y `align-items`, es por eso que nunca están siendo centradas los elementos de adentro. Tendrías que hacer [**flexible**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox#el_contenedor_flex) al div `contenedorInput` con la propiedad `display: flex`, ya que con `display: block` no te va a funcionar, y pues con esto ya quedaría:

```
.contenedorInput {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Código:

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.contenedor{
  border-radius: 15px;
  height: 280px;
  width: 70%;
  top: 100px;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: crimson;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.formularioClase{
  margin: 25px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.contenedorInput{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
  <h1>Calculadora con JS</h1>

  <form class="formularioClase" id="formCalculadoraID">
    <div class="contenedorInput">
      <label for="operandoA">Operando A</label>
      <input type="number" placeholder="Ingresa el primer operando" class="inputClass" id="operandoA"/>
    </div>
    <div class="contenedorInput">
      <label for="operandoB">Operando B</label>
      <input type="number" placeholder="Ingresa el segundo operando" class="inputClass" id="operandoB"/>
    </div>
  </form>

  <button class="botonResultado">Resultado</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Ay ay ay, te amo <3 jajjaja. Gracias!